# Failed to execute Dataflow job from GAE standard environment?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-dataflow, dataflow

I'm trying to start dataflow pipeline job from a servlet on GAE standard environment. The job reads from Cloud SQL database and writes in BigQuery, both in the same project. The cloud dataflow service account has all needed permissions (Storage Object Admin, Cloud SQL Client, BigQuery Admin, BigQuery Data Editor) I guess. I got the following exception:

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Interrupted while staging packages
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.util.PackageUtil.stageClasspathElements(PackageUtil.java:401)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.util.PackageUtil.stageClasspathElements(PackageUtil.java:273)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.util.GcsStager.stageFiles(GcsStager.java:82)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.util.GcsStager.stageDefaultFiles(GcsStager.java:70)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner.run(DataflowRunner.java:741)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner.run(DataflowRunner.java:186)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:315)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:301)
at com.mycompany.prj.servers.dataflow.PipelineExecutor.run(PipelineExecutor.java:138)
at com.mycompany.prj.servers.dataflow.CloudSqlToBigQueryExporter.run(CloudSqlToBigQueryExporter.java:226)
at com.mycompany.prj.servers.dataflow.CloudSqlToBigQueryExporter.doTest(CloudSqlToBigQueryExporter.java:281)
at com.mycompany.prj.server.web.CronServlet.doGet(Unknown Source)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:848)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1780)
at com.mycompany.prj.server.web.TxFilter.doFilter(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1767)
at com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter.doFilter(ObjectifyFilter.java:48)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1767)
at com.mycompany.prj.servers.web.HttpCrossOriginFilter.doFilter(HttpCrossOriginFilter.java:23)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1767)
at com.mycompany.prj.servers.web.LogSchemeFilter.doFilter(LogSchemeFilter.java:17)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1767)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:60)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1767)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:583)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:513)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.ParseBlobUploadHandler.handle(ParseBlobUploadHandler.java:111)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1182)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppEngineWebAppContext.doHandle(AppEngineWebAppContext.java:187)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:513)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:293)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:539)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:333)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.RpcConnection.handle(RpcConnection.java:216)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.RpcConnector.serviceRequest(RpcConnector.java:81)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:134)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchServletRequest(JavaRuntime.java:772)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchRequest(JavaRuntime.java:735)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:705)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:261)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:347)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1915)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.MoreFutures.get(MoreFutures.java:68)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.util.PackageUtil.stageClasspathElements(PackageUtil.java:384)
... 50 more
```

I managed to run it on GAE standard. The problem was that I never scheduled it on a cron job, just run it through URL trigger. So for one hour I scheduled a dozen of requests and most of them passed. But some failed with this exception:

```
Failed java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while staging packages
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while staging packages
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.util.PackageUtil.stageClasspathElements(PackageUtil.java:403)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.util.PackageUtil.stageClasspathElements(PackageUtil.java:273)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.util.GcsStager.stageFiles(GcsStager.java:82)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.util.GcsStager.stageDefaultFiles(GcsStager.java:70)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner.run(DataflowRunner.java:741)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner.run(DataflowRunner.java:186)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:315)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:301)
at com.mycompany.prj.servers.dataflow.PipelineExecutor.run(PipelineExecutor.java:138)
at com.mycompany.prj.servers.dataflow.CloudSqlToBigQueryExporter.run(CloudSqlToBigQueryExporter.java:245)
at com.mycompany.prj.servers.dataflow.CloudSqlToBigQueryExporter.doTestOnExp(CloudSqlToBigQueryExporter.java:304)
at com.mycompany.prj.servers.dataflow.CloudSqlToBigQueryExporter.doTestOnExp(CloudSqlToBigQueryExporter.java:285)
at com.mycompany.prj.server.web.CronServlet.doGet(Unknown Source)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:848)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1780)
at com.mycompany.prj.server.web.TxFilter.doFilter(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1767)
at com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter.doFilter(ObjectifyFilter.java:48)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1767)
at com.mycompany.prj.servers.web.HttpCrossOriginFilter.doFilter(HttpCrossOriginFilter.java:23)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1767)
at com.mycompany.prj.servers.web.LogSchemeFilter.doFilter(LogSchemeFilter.java:17)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1767)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:60)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1767)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:583)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:524)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.ParseBlobUploadHandler.handle(ParseBlobUploadHandler.java:111)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1182)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppEngineWebAppContext.doHandle(AppEngineWebAppContext.java:187)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:513)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:293)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:539)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:333)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.RpcConnection.handle(RpcConnection.java:216)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.RpcConnector.serviceRequest(RpcConnector.java:81)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:134)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchServletRequest(JavaRuntime.java:772)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchRequest(JavaRuntime.java:735)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:705)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:261)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Operation not allowed in a thread that is neither the original request thread nor a thread created by ThreadManager
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl$CurrentRequestThreadFactory.newThread(ApiProxyImpl.java:1310)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:619)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:932)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1367)
at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$ListeningDecorator.execute(MoreExecutors.java:537)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.asyncRunStage(CompletableFuture.java:1640)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.runAsync(CompletableFuture.java:1858)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.MoreFutures.supplyAsync(MoreFutures.java:101)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.util.PackageUtil.stagePackage(PackageUtil.java:172)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.util.PackageUtil.lambda$stageClasspathElements$2(PackageUtil.java:362)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniCompose(CompletableFuture.java:952)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniCompose.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:926)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.exec(CompletableFuture.java:443)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
```

My **appengine-web.xml** looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">

    <application>my-app-name</application>


    <version>1</version>
    <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
    <sessions-enabled>true</sessions-enabled>
    <runtime>java8</runtime>

    <system-properties>
        <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties"/>
        <property name="file.encoding" value="UTF-8" />
        <property name="DEFAULT_ENCODING" value="UTF-8" />
    </system-properties>

    <instance-class>F1</instance-class>

    <automatic-scaling>
        <min-idle-instances>0</min-idle-instances>
        <max-idle-instances>1</max-idle-instances>
    </automatic-scaling>

</appengine-web-app>
```

The cron servlet is pretty simple:

```
public class CronServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
        String command = req.getParameter("command");
        if (command == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (command.equals("dataflow-job-test")) {
            CloudSqlToBigQueryExporter.doTestOnExp();
            //return;
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
        doGet(req, resp);
    }
}
```

and the cron.yaml is like this:

```
cron:
- url: '/cron?command=dataflow-job-test'
  schedule: 'every 5 minutes'
  description: 'Dataflow job execution test'
```

Comment: Could you tell me your aim with this pipeline ? Could you share the steps you took to configure the pipeline?

Comment: @AlexandreMoraes I'm trying to schedule every day export from Cloud SQL database (PostgreSQL in particular) to BigQuery table. Configuring the pipeline is done properly since I managed to start it from "main" method. But trying to execute it from cron servlet it fails. I found this blog [post](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/scheduling-dataflow-pipelines-using-app-engine-cron-service-or-cloud-functions) where It is mentioned that you could only trigger pipeline jobs from flexible GAE, but I was wondering if it's still relevant, bacause it's posted 5 years ago.

Comment: Can you share more details like the `app.yaml`, `cron.yaml` and the code of your servlet?

Comment: I added more info in the post. Thank you!

Comment: The dataflow job is pretty simple - count on around 200 sql entries from one table and write the number in BQ table, all in the same project.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are getting here, as described in the error message:

```
Operation not allowed in a thread that is neither the original request thread nor a thread created by ThreadManager
```

Is because your servlet is creating new Threads which is not allowed in App Engine unless you use [GAE's Thread Manager](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/runtime#threads) intead of using tradicional Threads.

So in order to fix that you need to change your code to generate threads using the [`currentRequestThreadFactory()`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/ThreadManager#currentRequestThreadFactory()).

Comment: In fact, it is the pipeline runner that creates new Threads. I tried executing the starting of the pipeline from a thread using `ThreadManager.currentRequestThreadFactory().newThread(runnableThatStartsThePipelineJob).start();` but without any success. Starting it like that `new Thread(runnableThatStartsThePipelineJob).start()` seems to be working, but I cannot explain it to myself, why.

Comment: Indeed this is a strange thing, starting threads with `ThreadManager` is the recommended and it should work. If you want to report this I suggest you to open a Customer Issue in [Google's Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187191&template=0), so they can be aware of this problem. Glad to know that you made it work though.